# Safari issue For disable all select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery line which works in all browsers other than safari MAC Latest.

I need this because the number of `select` can be non countable.

```
$('select[id*="ddOperator_').prop('disabled', true);
```

We can check safari issues [here](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Typo? `'select[id*="ddOperator"]'`

Comment: Thanks it worked , My eyes did't cached missing ']'

Comment: Are you sure it worked in other browsers then...? x)

Comment: Yes, it was worked lucky